# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Invalid object name 'Classroom.signUp'

Tags: node.js, sql-server

i will try to make login, using passport and sql server but  after authenticate show the next error

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Invalid object name 'Classroom.signUp'.
    at handleError (C:\Users\Amanda\Desktop\Classroom\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:551:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Parser. (C:\Users\Amanda\Desktop\Classroom\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:618:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Parser. (C:\Users\Amanda\Desktop\Classroom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:54:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (C:\Users\Amanda\Desktop\Classroom\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:291:12)
(node:5336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

my passporr.js file:

```
const passport = require('passport');
   const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
   const sql = require('mssql')
   const pool = require('../database/conexion');

   passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
     usernameField: 'username',
     passwordField: 'passwords',
   passReqToCallback: true
  },(req, username, passwords, done) => {
    console.log(username)
    const request= pool.request();
   //request.input('username',sql.NVarChar,username);
  // request.input('passwords',sql.NVarChar,passwords);
  request.query(`SELECT * FROM dbo.signUp WHERE [singUp].                        
  [username]='+@username+' AND [signUp].[passwords]='+@passwords+'`
  ,(user,err)=>{

     done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'Bienvenido'+user.username)); 
   });

  }));



passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
 });

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done)=> {
  const rows = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM  [Classroom].[signUp]  WHERE id =${id}`);
done(null, rows);
});
```

Comment: That code implies you're storing passwords as plain text in your database. That is a really bad idea. Ideally you should be salting and hashing the values. Also, although I know nothing about node.js, the syntax `[username]='+@username+'` looks wrong. Are you sure it shouldn't be  `[username] = @username`? ([nodejs mssql insert with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289848/nodejs-mssql-insert-with-parameters) implies it should be.)

Comment: Larnu, i update my query request.query(`SELECT * FROM dbo.signUp WHERE [singUp].[username]='${username}+' AND [signUp].[passwords]='${passwords}'`