# Store JSON as string in Azure SQL Database

Tags: node.js, json, sql-server

I'm trying to insert JSON as a string into a table of Azure SQL database. The column 'Info' was created as nvarchar(max). But I get an error in both ways I tried:

**Attempt 1:** send JSON as object

INSERT INTO productsTable (Id, Name, Url, Info) VALUES (123456, 'Name of product', 'https://www.example.com/product/123456', {'test':'here','nested':{'itest':'ivalue','itest2':100}})

Results in an error:

```
"error": {
  "code": "EREQUEST",
  "originalError": {
     "info": {
        "name": "ERROR",
        "event": "errorMessage",
        "number": 102,
        "state": 1,
        "class": 15,
        "message": "Incorrect syntax near 'test'.",
        "serverName": "myapp",
        "procName": "",
        "lineNumber": 1
     }
  }
```

**Attempt 2:** JSON.stringify the json before sending for write.

```
INSERT INTO CampaignDetailsTable (Id, Name, Url, Info) VALUES (123456, 'Name of produc', 'https://www.example.com/product/123456', '{\'test\':\'here\',\'nested\':{\'itest\':\'ivalue\',\'itest2\':100}}')
```

Results in the same error:

```
"code": "EREQUEST",
"originalError": {
  "info": {
     "name": "ERROR",
     "event": "errorMessage",
     "number": 102,
     "state": 1,
     "class": 15,
     "message": "Incorrect syntax near 'test'.",
     "serverName": "myapp",
     "procName": "",
     "lineNumber": 1
  }
```

}

I don't care about what format it is stored in SQL, as long as I can revert to JSON object in my code after I read it back.

Comment: Its just a string so when you are doing a literal insert it follows all the rules for escaping quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server. Also since it is a string it must be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: You can post it in here: https://www.freeformatter.com/sql-escape.html. Copy the result, and put another set of qutoes around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a string like any other so at the very least it needs to be surrounded by single quotes:

```
'My String'
```

Your string happens to have single quotes in it so you need to escape those:

```
'you''re doing it wrong'
```

I pasted your example in here

https://www.freeformatter.com/sql-escape.html

It gave me this:

```
{''test'':''here'',''nested'':{''itest'':''ivalue'',''itest2'':100}}
```

You just need to surround that in quotes, because it's a string literal. So this is what should be in your insert.

```
'{''test'':''here'',''nested'':{''itest'':''ivalue'',''itest2'':100}}'
```

Run this in management studio to test:

```
SELECT '{''test'':''here'',''nested'':{''itest'':''ivalue'',''itest2'':100}}'
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid . I had also tried making it a string literal which failed, now I see I should have escaped single quotes with another single quote. I"m all set.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to parameterize the query instead of escaping quotes? Improperly escaping strings and concatenating them into queries is one way that SQL injection attacks happen.

Comment: Yes it would be better.

Comment: @alroc , I'm able to parameterize for Azure Storage table. But I have not been able to find any way to do that for Azure SQL inserts.  I'm using node.js and mssql and the command I'm using is:
----------------------------------------
sql.connect(dbConfig)
      .then(pool => {

         return pool.request()
            .query(jsonQueryPacket.query);

      })
-------------------
I'll ask a separate question on how to parametrize it. But if you have any quick suggestions then I'd love to try it.

Comment: @Curious101 have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48289995/1324345 for parameterizing queries with node.js

Comment: Thanks @alroc. This looks promising, appreciate you sharing the link.