# Parameterize the INSERT statement on SQL Server running on Azure in node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

My app server is in node.js and I'm storing records in SQL Server database running on Azure. I'm using the mssql library (link below). How do I parameterize the Insert statement to prevent against SQL injection attacks.

mssql -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Here is my code:

```
const sql = require("mssql");

var    dbConfig = {
              server: azureSqlDbServerUrl, // Use your SQL server name
              database: azureSqlDbName, // Database to connect to
              user: azureSqlDbUsername, // Use your username
              password: azureSqlDbPassword, // Use your password
              port: 1433,
                 // Since we're on Windows Azure, we need to set the following options
              options: {
                 encrypt: true,
                 enableArithAbort: false
              }
           };


// myQuery holds:  
// INSERT INTO productsTable Id, Name, Url, Info) VALUES (123456, 'Name of product', 'https://www.example.com/product/123456', '{''test'':''here'',''nested'':{''itest'':''ivalue'',''itest2'':100}}' )


sql.connect(dbConfig)
  .then(pool => {

     return pool.request()
        .query( myQuery );

  }).then(result => {

      callback(0, result);

   }).catch(err => { // ... error checks
      console.log("Error occured: " + err);
      callback(err, null);
   });
```

I've looked through the documentation on mssql and it doesn't really go into parameterizing the insert query. Other SQL Server docs have not been particularly help either.

Comment: Please check in below link. It already has a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289848/nodejs-mssql-insert-with-parameters/48289995

Comment: @Nirmalkumar Thanks. I'll check it out now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs mssql insert with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289848/nodejs-mssql-insert-with-parameters)